# Linux network interfaces take so long to come up

Tags: linux, networking

When any of the network interfaces on my x86 server comes up (1GbE port with igb driver, or 10GbE port with ixgbe driver), whether it's been done using ifup or by enabling the switch ports it's connected to, it takes on the order of 30 seconds before the interface is working (ping out or in).

They are configured with simple static IP addresses in /etc/network/interfaces, so I feel that they should become active immediately.

```
iface ge0 inet static
    address 10.63.4.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.63.4.1
```

I've searched the web extensively, but can't find a thing. tcpdump shows the port receiving broadcast ARP requests, but not replying to them or sending any other packets. After the ~30 seconds elapses, it sends out an ARP reply and ICMPs start flowing. Might it be pausing to detect duplicate IP addresses?

This is a problem because my manufacturing scenario involves reconfiguring and restarting the network several times. Other than this issue, the process would take seconds instead of minutes.

Comment: Have you tried to disable autonegotiation on switch and computer?

Comment: Thanks; I found last night that packets are being received but not sent, so I think it's past the autonegotiation phase.

Answer (score 1):

30 seconds is pretty much how long it takes for a default spanning tree port configuration to start forwarding traffic.

The port will go through different states (e.g. listening while it *listens* for BPDUs or learning when it's *learning* MAC addresses) until it gets to a forwarding state and starts, you guessed it, *forwarding* traffic.

Depending on your switch's vendor and model you should be able to tweak it. Please bear in mind that if you just disable spanning tree you're at risk of network loops that could bring your whole infrastructure down. It is not recommended to get rid of it on non-controlled or non-isolated networks.

Comment: +1 Sounds like someone needs to do a "portfast enable".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys!

The problem indeed turned out to be spanning tree. "show spanning-tree" on the switch showed the interface spending a long time in the blocking state.

After placing the (bonded) interfaces in question into portfast mode, traffic passes immediately after link up.

```
#config
#interface Port-Channel1
(config-if-Po1)#spanning-tree portfast
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any messages in dmesg from network interfaces? Try this command after startup:

`dmesg | grep "net\|^eth\|^igb\|^ixgbe"`

Also it may be configured STP(Spanning Tree Protocol ) on switch, which you connected to. Try to check out configuration your network equipment for getting spanning tree mode on ports  which your server connected.